# Trigonometry, isosceles triangle

Tags: trigonometry

Given the chatetus of $12$cm and the angle $\beta=76^{\circ}$ of an isosceles triangle calculate it's surface area. Using trigonometry ofc.?

Comment: Is $\;\beta\;$ one of the two equal basis angles, or the angle at the apex? And "chatetus" seems to be related to "leg" in straight angle triangles, which is obviously not the case here.

Comment: It's one of the two base angles.

Comment: And by chatetus I mean the 2 equal sides that aren't the base, sorry English is not my firsh laguange so I'm a bit shaky with mathematical terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

[image]

Say $\;AB=AC=12\;,\;\;\angle C=\angle B=76^\circ\;$ . Since $\;\angle A=180^\circ-2\cdot76^\circ=26^\circ\;$ , we get
$${}$$
$$S_\Delta= \frac{12^2}2\sin26^\circ$$